# C# access main thread instance without holding a reference

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, instance

Is it possible to get the instance of the main-thread *without holding a reference* which is set on application startup? Passing main thread instances around when initializing modules is not a very good solution in my point of view.

Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean by "main-thread"? If you mean the `Thread` object for the thread which is running `Main`, I'm not sure why you'd need that. There's not much that can be done with it that is useful.

Comment: Use Invoke and Thread.CurrentThread.

Comment: I need access to the `IsAlive` property. This is needed when the TPL is no option. Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: You need to check `IsAlive` on the main thread? Why? And what does TPL have to do with any of this? Are you polling for main thread status to know when to exit child threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain a reference it needs to be held *somewhere*. It is up to you to decide where exactly you would like to hold it.

> Passing main thread instances around when initializing modules is not a very good solution in my point of view.

Passing main thread instances on initialization is not the only option available to you. You have several other options:

- **Make the reference `static` in a well-known module** - this is the simplest options that has a very limited impact, because main thread never changes.
- **Make a registry of threads, indicating which thread ID is main** - this option lets you maintain thread hierarchy
- **Use inverse-of-control container, and let it set the reference for you** - this is an advanced option that may be applicable in IOC environments. It lets you decouple modules accessing the main thread from the main module of your project.

> I need access to the `IsAlive` property

You could make a single module with a `static` reference to the main thread, and give it `IsMainThreadAlive` property. You could further encapsulate checking for `IsAlive` by providing, statically, an event that informs subscribers that the main thread has exited. This would serve as a nice decoupling option for modules that need to know when the main thread has exited.

Comment: Your first solution is what I'm usualy using, thought there are some alternatives. Thank you.